# Python virtualenv picks up wrong library

Tags: python, virtualenv, qgis, pygments

```
$ virtualenv --version
13.0.3
```

I create a new virtualenv with Python3 without access to global site packages.

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv_pygments --python=/usr/local/bin/python3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in venv_pygments/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in venv_pygments/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Then I use the virtualenv's Python3 interpreter and try to import `pygments`

```
$ cd venv_pygments 
$ venv_pygments  bin/python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, May  1 2015, 19:14:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygments
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/pygments/__init__.py", line 46
    except TypeError, err:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`pip freeze` though only shows these packages

```
$ bin/pip freeze
wheel==0.24.0
```

So it seems like the virtualenv's Python3 is accessing global site packages. How can I avoid that?

It doesn't change when I install pygments for the virtualenv

```
$ bin/pip install pygments
Collecting pygments
  Using cached Pygments-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments-2.0.2
$ venv_pygments  bin/python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, May  1 2015, 19:14:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygments
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/pygments/__init__.py", line 46
    except TypeError, err:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

---

Note: The original question was updated based on the comments.

Comment: try to use relative or absolute paths for pip and python. May be you actually use system python resources.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip with `pip install --upgrade pip` like it is said in the output message?

Comment: @miindlek yes did that. No difference?

Comment: @SaschaGottfried could you give an example how I would use pip with a relative/absolute path?

Comment: pip is not the problem, since pip installed successfully. Investigate version of virtualenv and how to use it properly.

Comment: Now I am pretty sure, your problem is related to access to global site-packages. Find relevant option for mkvirtualenv to restrict access to global site-packages.

Comment: does all this work with your system python?

Comment: How did you install Python3?

Comment: What happens when you do not create a virtualenv and import pygments with your Python 3.4 installation?

Answer (score 4):

Create isolated environment without access to global site-packages. Either enable/disable that behaviour intentionally. Recent versions disable access by default.

I assume you want an isolated environment to test Python 3.3.4.
Below I am using virtualenv provided by system python 2.7.6

```
$ virtualenv --version
1.11.2

$ virtualenv
You must provide a DEST_DIR
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity.
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
                        (/usr/bin/python)
  --clear               Clear out the non-root install and start from scratch.
  --no-site-packages    DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility.
                        Not having access to global site-packages is now the
                        default behavior.
  --system-site-packages
                        Give the virtual environment access to the global
                        site-packages.
  --always-copy         Always copy files rather than symlinking.
  --unzip-setuptools    Unzip Setuptools when installing it.
  --relocatable         Make an EXISTING virtualenv environment relocatable.
                        This fixes up scripts and makes all .pth files
                        relative.
  --no-setuptools       Do not install setuptools (or pip) in the new
                        virtualenv.
  --no-pip              Do not install pip in the new virtualenv.
  --extra-search-dir=DIR
                        Directory to look for setuptools/pip distributions in.
                        This option can be used multiple times.
  --never-download      DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility.
                        This option has no effect. Virtualenv never downloads
                        pip or setuptools.
  --prompt=PROMPT       Provides an alternative prompt prefix for this
                        environment.
  --setuptools          DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility.
                        This option has no effect.
  --distribute          DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility.
                        This option has no effect.
```

I create a virtualenv, change into the directory and use relative paths to address python interpreter and pip from inside this virtualenv.

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv_pygments
New python executable in venv_pygments/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ cd venv_pygments/
$ bin/pip install pygments
Downloading/unpacking pygments
  Downloading Pygments-2.0.2-py2-none-any.whl (672kB): 672kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments
Cleaning up...
$ bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygments
>>> pygments.__version__
'2.0.2'
```

While creating your virtualenv you need to keep using the option

> --python=/usr/local/bin/python3

to refer to your Python 3.3.4 interpreter as you already do.

A recent default virtualenv usually has only a few packages installed. If yours has more you may have access to global site-packages.

```
$ bin/pip freeze
Pygments==2.0.2
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: Following your steps, I still get the same error when I create a virtualenv for python3. After creating a new virtualenv,  pip freeze gives me no site-packages like expected.

Comment: Update your question then to reflect the things you did. Try importing pygments before installing it. This should raise two different exceptions. First one should indicate a missing package, since you hace not installed it yet.

Comment: Get another Python 3.4 installation, repeat all steps. Or Investigate files and folders (site-packages) in your virtualenv to find pygments resources or *.pth files